# TPOT : Where is te the best pipeline (.py file) exported after fitting when working in COLAB

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, tpot

I'm running the example of MNIST dataset classification provided by TPOT documentation page. I'm doing this by using Google Colab, nonetheless I can't find the code with the best pipeline that is retrieved by tpot after training.

Can you please help me to figure out where this .py file is saved?

```py
from tpot import TPOTClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

digits = load_digits()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(digits.data, digits.target,
                                                    train_size=0.75, test_size=0.25)

tpot = TPOTClassifier(generations=5, population_size=50, verbosity=2)
tpot.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(tpot.score(X_test, y_test))
tpot.export('tpot_mnist_pipeline.py')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be in your working directory.

I also encountered this problem while running TPOT on virtual machines. For this I committed some code which allows you to also export to string.

Use:

```py
print(tpot.export())
```

and it will print the pipeline code to screen